# How to get best selling product with its image by object manager in magento2 .phtml file?

Tags: magento2, phtml

How to get best selling product with its image by object manager in magento2 .phtml file ???

Answer (score 2):

**Try  below code :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory'); 
$collection = $productCollection->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection'); 

$collection->setPeriod('month');
//$collection->setPeriod('year');
//$collection->setPeriod('day');

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    print_r($item->getData());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. that code working but product image, product url not showing. Plz check the attached output bellow.
Array
(
    [period] => 2018-01-01
    [qty_ordered] => 1.0000
    [product_id] => 1483
    [product_name] => Minerva LumaTech&trade; V-Tee-XS-Blue
    [product_price] => 0.0000
    [orig_data] => 
)